# Java Swing - black border when resizing JFrame

Tags: java, performance, swing, repaint

I have not used Swing in ages and now that I've had to pick it up again I've encountered the same slight yet annoying problem on both Windows 8 and Xubuntu 14.04.

When I resize a JFrame by dragging one of it's borders outwards with the mouse-cursor, the windows content-pane seems to lag behind the frame itself, thus creating a black border of varying size in the direction in which the JFrame is enlarged. As stated this happens on different machines and operating systems, It's definitely not an implementation problem; Netbeans exhibits this behavior as well. I have Java version 1.8.0_45 installed in both cases.

Does anybody else experience this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the layout?

Comment: Yes I have, I assure you the code is not at fault, the problem occurs if I so much as create an empty JFrame.
I'd just like to know if this is kind of behavior is common, does netbeans do it on your computer?

Comment: No, there's nothing you can do, this is caused at the core of the API. You could try reducing the complexity of the UI, but I doubt it'll help much

Comment: This happens to me on a Swing application that I developed, when re-sizing using a Sash object. There is not really a way to change this as far as I have found. It's pretty common.

Comment: In dont't remember this being the case in earlier releases, has this started recently? And is JavaFX any better when it comes to performance?

Comment: Nope, it's been there since 1.3 since I started. A lot comes down to the OS and the rendering engine been used and the complexity of the UI. It's probably a over optimization on Swing/AWT trying to reduce the number if times it needs to invalidate/repaint the UI. As to if it happens in FX, I don't know, it'll come down to how often the API is willing to update the view when it's parent container changes